# How can we get upper bound in terms of Big Oh notation using Master theorem?

Tags: time-complexity, recursion, big-o-notation, master-theorem

The recursion is:

```
T(n) = 5T(n/2) + O(n)
```

I solved for the time complexity using Master theorem and found Θ(n^2). but, the question has asked to find the upper bound in terms of Big Oh. Is there any principle to convert it into Big Oh form? I read some examples where they substituted some values and deduced but I couldn't understand.

Update:
I apologize for writing the recursion equation wrong. The actual recursive equation for this question is:

```
T(n) = 2(n-1) + O(n)
```

Comment: $\Theta$ is subset of $O$, so if you obtain first, then you have, also, second.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your reasoning is wrong. It is in $\Theta(n^{\log_2(5)})$. Hence, it is also in $O(n^{\log_2(5)})$.

**Answer to the update**:
Also, for the update part, it is wrong. You can find it by a straightforward expansion (no need to master theorem):

$$
T(n) = 2T(n-1) + O(n) = 2(2T(n-2) + O(n-1)) + O(n) \\ = 2^2T(n-2) + O(n-1) + O(n) = \cdots = \\ 2^n * T(0) + O(1) + O(2) + \cdots + O(n) \in O(2^n)
$$

Comment: I just realized that I typed the wrong expression.  Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @five_star_021 You shouldn't totally change the question to another question. You should post a new question for that matter.

Comment: @five_star_021 it's better now. You can find the answer for the updated part as well.